# Are there any mac epub readers that support vertical scrolling?

Tags: macos, mac, epub, ereader

I find it much easier scrolling down on to the next page, rather than going left to right. Does anyone know if there are any epub readers that suppor this?

Answer (score 1):

There's at least [Bookle](http://www.stairways.com/main/bookle). It still seems sort of unfinished though and the last update was about a year ago.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)'s own viewer can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this myself. For the record, I found [Murasaki](http://genjiapp.com/mac/murasaki/index_en.html).